# Keeping chunks loaded without player

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have an automated golem farm on my Minecraft map (Xbox) that doesn't work when I'm too far away because the chunk it's in isn't loaded from where I usually am. So if I want it to work, I have to stand somewhere near it. Is there any way I can keep it loaded at all? Like, if there was something running in the area, such as a minecart? Or will it not work at all without a player?

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible with the current limitations set on console editions of minecraft.

Comment: I wonder if the hopper trick works on xbox?

Comment: @ender Unfortunately, Xbox doesn't have hoppers yet.

Comment: I really dont understand why riot doesn't have vanilla chunk loaders at this point.

Comment: Soon though, we shall have thy hopper... And all the cares of the world will blow away in the breeze... Ahhhh....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but no. A players presence within a certain distance of a possible spawning location. Is what determines spawning.

My suggestion:
If you have a second controller. Set up a dummy profile on your xbox. Sign it in to the game. Then leave that character by your farm. You'll have to put up with splitscreen. But, I just don't see it any other way. Other than afk-ing. Checking back to harvest from time to time.